# why is r logger returning code not results (counts)

Tags: r, logging

Using r logger for returning a log but it is returning the code. In the past it worked fine.

example of what is returned:

INFO [2022-08-27 07:13:22] {package_log}::{func_string} returned {nrow(result)} rows

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. It's not clear at the moment exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that somewhere you changed the default formatter for logging.

Long story short, reproducible and a fix:

```r
library(logger)
log_info("hello {nrow(mtcars)}")
# INFO [2022-08-28 17:32:00] hello 32
log_formatter(formatter_sprintf)
log_info("hello {nrow(mtcars)}")
# INFO [2022-08-28 17:33:56] hello {nrow(mtcars)}
log_formatter(formatter_glue)
log_info("hello {nrow(mtcars)}")
# INFO [2022-08-28 17:34:00] hello 32
```

You can read more about formatters in [Customizing the Format and the Destination of a Log Record](https://daroczig.github.io/logger/articles/customize_logger.html), one of the package vignettes.

Comment: thank you r2evans, very efficient - solved the problem